# Не могу задать свойству внутреннего объекта значение внешнего объекта, внешний объект undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть внешний объект `outer`

В внутреннем объекте `inner` хочу присвоить значение свойству , но не получается.

```html
<script>
const outer = {
  data: [100, 500, 1000],

  inner: {
    'prop': outer.data,
  }
}

console.log(outer.config.prop);
</script>
```

Выводит ошибку что `outer undefined`.

*Почему так происходит* и *как установить внутреннему свойству prop значение* ?

Если есть ссылки объясняющие  этот вопрос пожалуйста вставьте их.

Comment: Мой вопрос более узкий  чем так называемый ее дубликат , и  развернутый ответ  на данный вопрос  поможет многим.